# Efficient way to replace part of a string with another string

Tags: regex, go

The task is to remove leading backslash "\" from this example value (23,07 USD) so in the end I end up with (23,07 USD). This `(23\,07 USD)` is part of a longer string where 23,07 is value and USD is example currency. This longer string can be something like `fjsdkjfd$$klsgf|fj15%fdsjkl|gdag-63431|(34\,21 USD)|czjfkljsdklfjk`
Is there more efficient way to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

var (
    s = `fjsdkjfd$$klsgf|fj15%fdsjkl|gdag-63431|(34\,21 USD)|czjfkljsdklfjk`
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\(\d+\\,{0,1}\d{1,2}\ {0,1}\w{2,3}\)`)
    s1 := re.Find([]byte(s))
    s2 := strings.Replace(string(s1), `\,`, `,`, 1)
    s3 := strings.Replace(s, string(s1), s2, 1)
    fmt.Println(s3)
}
```

Comment: I can't comprehend what you're doing with the regexp and the double replace call... are you trying to handle some special case or something? Why don't you just use replace once with the proper arguments? https://go.dev/play/p/ROxGnPLsDR7

Comment: @mkopriva
sure, but this replaces everything so `fjsdkjfd\,$$klsgf|fj1\,5%fdsjkl|gdag-63431|(34\,21 USD)|czjfkl\,jsdk\,\,\,lfjk` :) I'm not interested in touching anything else besides this value :)

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Code:**

```
func removeLeadingBackslash(s string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\(\d+\\,\d+ \w+\)`)
    return re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(s, func(matched string) string {
        return strings.Replace(matched, `\,`, `,`, 1)
    })
}
```

**With more tests:**

```
func main() {
    testCases := []string{
        "fjsdkjfd$$klsgf|fj15%fdsjkl|gdag-63431|(34\\,21 USD)|czjfkljsdklfjk",
        "This is a test string: (12\\,34 EUR).",
        "Another example: (9\\,99 USD) a sentence.",
        "No leading backslash in this one: (56,78 USD).",
        "Test string with (1\\,23 USD) in the middle.",
    }
    for _, s := range testCases {
        result := removeLeadingBackslash(s) 
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
fjsdkjfd$$klsgf|fj15%fdsjkl|gdag-63431|(34,21 USD)|czjfkljsdklfjk
This is a test string: (12,34 EUR).
Another example: (9,99 USD) a sentence.       
No leading backslash in this one: (56,78 USD).
Test string with (1,23 USD) in the middle.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *capture pattern*, and replace the *match* with, `($1,$2)`.

```
\((\d+)\\,?(\d{1,2} ?\w{2,3})\)
```